# How to force a PDF to be rendered without downloading?

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe

When I use `<iframe src="some_pdf_file.pdf/>` on a PDF that has the header `Content-Disposition` set to `attachment` the `iframe` decides to download the file instead of rendering it. This is reasonable behavior, however I want to force the PDF to be rendered in the `iframe`.

How can I do this? Is it possible to download the file and then change the `Content-Disposition` header to `inline`?

```js
<object
  data='https://pdfjs-express.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docs/choosing-a-pdf-viewer.pdf'
  type="application/pdf"
  width="500"
  height="678"
>
  <iframe
    src='https://pdfjs-express.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docs/choosing-a-pdf-viewer.pdf'
    width="500"
    height="678"
  >
    <p>This browser does not support PDF!</p>
  </iframe>
</object>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850298/how-can-i-force-a-browser-to-not-download-a-file-with-content-dispositionattach

Comment: @KJ your comment does not contribute anything to answering the original question.